# How to format UTF-8 for freemarker and .fo.ftl document in ofbiz?

Tags: utf-8, freemarker, ofbiz

I'm using freemarker to display data in ofbiz and then I use .fo.ftl to export that data to pdf format, but had an error with my font in my pdf file. So, how can I set UTF-8 for it ?

Thanks!

Comment: You should tell what the error message is if you ask something like this. Also, UTF-8 for what exactly? What happens with the generated FO, is it written out to a file? If so, is the content of that file wrong, and in what way?

Comment: @ddekany It just error font, but I was found problem. I using Linux, but my server was configured default font is Area, so I just setup my system font to add Area font and problem was resolved.